# Freebase quick start demo return empty result

Tags: api, google-api, freebase

I'm going over [Get Started with the Freebase API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/getting-started) and
When trying to send the following request from the browser url box: 
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?q=bob&key=MY_API_KEY

I'm getting
{"status":"200 OK","result":[]}

I activated freebase in the API console and used browser API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for catching that. It's a typo. It should be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=bob&key=MY_API_KEY
```